# Condition JSON reads in scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have two classes that inherit from a common parent. I would like to have one common JSON reader in the parent that will return an appropriate child based on supplied JSON. It is easier to explain this with a sample snippet below;

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsPath, JsonValidationError, Reads}

sealed abstract class Animal(sound: String)

case class Goat(hooves: String) extends Animal("meh")

case class Cat(needsMilk: Boolean) extends Animal("meow")

val json ="""{"type": "goat", "hooves": "All good for climbing trees"}"""

object Animal {
  val isSupportedAnimal: Reads[String] =
    Reads.StringReads.filter(JsonValidationError("Unsupported animal"))(str => {
      List("goat", "cat").contains(str)
    })

  val animalReads: Reads[Animal] = ((JsPath \ "type").read[String](isSupportedAnimal) and
    //if animal is cat, use the cat specific reads and return a cat object
    //if animal is goat, use goat specific reads and return a goat
    )()
}
```

Given the `json` in the snippet, I would like the have `Goat` object because the specified type is `goat`.

I am new to scala so I might be approaching the problem in a wrong way. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `Map`:

```
sealed abstract class Animal(val sound: String) // You probably want a val here, btw
final case class Goat(hooves: String) extends Animal("meh")
final case class Cat(needsMilk: Boolean) extends Animal("meow")

object Animal {
  val readers: Map[String, Reads[_ <: Animal]] = Map(
    "goat" -> implicitly[Reads[Goat]],
    "cat" -> implicitly[Reads[Cat]],
    // Sidenote: Trailing commas   ^ make future modification easy
  )
  // Bonus: Set[String] <: String => Boolean, so you get isSupportedAnimal for free
  // val isSupportedAnimal: String => Boolean = readers.keys

  implicit val animalReads: Reads[Animal] = new Reads[Animal] {
    def reads(s: JsValue): JsResult[Animal] = {
      val tpe = (s \ "type").as[String]
      val read = readers.get(tpe)
      read.map(_.reads(s)).getOrElse(JsError(s"Unsupported animal: $tpe"))
    }
  }
}
```

If you'd rather not have this boilerplate, you can look into [this library](https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-derived-codecs) (which uses shapeless).

Comment: Thanks. I see the light in this answer. I am trying to get your snippet to compile at the moment. I would appreciate if you can put something that compiles but I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to make an custom reader like this:

```
implicit val animalReads = new Reads[Animal] {
    def reads(js: JsValue): Animal = {
      (js \ "type").as[String] match {
        case "cat" => Cat( (js \ "needsMilk").as[Boolean] )
        case "goat" => Goat( (js \ "hooves").as[String] )
        case _ => throw new JsonValidationError("Unsupported animal")
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would that work with the automatic validation that you get when you make a `Reads[Animal]` Say you have a controller action as one below
`def saveAnimal = Action(validateJson[Animal]) { request: Request[Animal] =>`

Comment: Thanks for taking time to work through this. I have accepted @HTNW because with it can I can chain other readers in the `Goat` and `Cat` readers.